# Parent Container not "maintaining" the same height

Tags: html, css

I have a bizarre CSS bug happening.

I was able to adjust the height of main #app to always be 100% of a given **screen size**.
This worked through every page of my app but one. I don't know what's possibly causing the conflict as the classes are named **identically** on every page.

The only difference is that some pages have less content than others. But should this **matter**? I've tried adding `!important`  but no dice.

I have my:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

 #app {
  background: url('someurl') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block; //this is what fixed in other pages
}

#app .child-container {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

The bug looks like the example bellow:
Ps: I removed the background image and added a red color just to show how the height of the `#app` is changing inexplicably.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Give  min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `vh` unit instead of percentage. 1 vh represents 1% of the viewports,

therefore

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

just min-height should suffice.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 2):

If you want an HTML element to fill the screen  height ( or width )
you can use 'vh/vw' ( for view height/width)  instead of '%' on the body

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```